# Piping input to a shell command and keeping the created shell alive

Tags: bash, shell, piping

My overarching program is a shell script. This shell script calls a C program that I need to pipe input to, and ultimately the C program will create a shell.

However, when I pipe my input into the C program within the shell script

```
Do_Other_Stuff
./my_prog < file1
```

I can't get the shell to stay alive. Running just,

```
Do_Other_Stuff
./my_prog
```

works, as I have to input the stdin myself, and the shell correctly spawns when my_prog exits. I'm pretty sure wrapping up the ./my_prog call in a C program, and compiling and running that would work, but I'm curious as to whether there's a cleaner way with shell.

I've tried several combinations of using `cat file1 | ./my_prog` and using `&` in different situations, and haven't had any success.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you expect the shell to run an interactive session after your commands have completed? You could use a temp file and pass it in with `--rcfile`.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
cat file1 - | ./myprog
```

Many programs recognize the "filename" `-` to mean stdin.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to the C program source code?  My guess is that the C program is using `istty(0)` to determine if stdin is coming from a terminal.  It probably only creates an interactive shell when that is the case.  Using stdin redirection, whether from a file or a pipe, means that `istty(0)` returns false.